# Laravel blade foreach where condition with komma-separated string

Tags: laravel

I want to loop through with all main categories. This is to use where-condition to check which categories have the id on main category and output it.

The DB look like this:

```
id | name | parent_ids
10 | Cat1 |
12 | Cat3 |
17 | Cat2 | 10,12
25 | Cat4 | 12


@foreach($lagerMainCategories-\>where('parent_ids', $lagerMainCategory-\>id) AS $lagerSubCategories)
    <li>
    
    {{$lagerSubCategories-\>name}} ({{$lagerSubCategories-\>id}})</li>
    
    
    @include('Skote.layouts.lagerCategory.lagerSubCategory', \['lagerMainCategory' =\> $lagerSubCategories\])
    @endforeach
```

I get out

```
Cat1
Cat3
Cat4
```

I want to

```
Cat1
Cat2
Cat3
Cat2
Cat4
```

Comment: The item with ID 17  doesn't belong to any item. (cause there should be only an int not a string comma separated), I think you should redo the relationship between Categories or redesign the DB schema for that. I was having same design and I used parent_ids as array but it's not a good idea.

Comment: try to use whereIn and explode ids by comma ```$lagerMainCategories-\>whereIn('parent_ids', explode(",",$lagerMainCategory-\>id))```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for Help. I have found a solution.

```
    @foreach($lagerMainCategories->where('parent_ids', '!=', null) AS $lagerSubCategories)
    @if(in_array($lagerMainCategory->id, explode(',', $lagerSubCategories->parent_ids)))
        <li>{{$lagerSubCategories->name}} ({{$lagerSubCategories->id}}) </li>
        @include('Skote.layouts.lagerCategory.lagerSubCategory', ['lagerMainCategory' => $lagerSubCategories])
    @endif
@endforeach
```